# How handle Android Device 180 degree rotation (reverseLandscape)? - onConfigurationChanged is not called

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-activity, onconfigurationchanged

When rotating phone 180 degree onConfigurationChanged Callback is not called, only works when changing  rotation from portrait to landscape and vice verse, however rotating 180 degree when on landscape view is rotated however onConfigurationChanged  callback is not called. How to handle 180 rotating.

my Manifest

```
<activity
            android:name="com.myApp.Activity"
            android:configChanges="screenSize|smallestScreenSize|screenLayout|orientation"/>
```

my Activity

```
@Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        Toast.makeText(this, "rotated", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```

Comment: for dealing with lifecycle-events in a better and elegant way use `viewmodels`, take a look at the [official docs](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel) for more info

Comment: @rcs if you mean deleting android:configChanges in manifest and working with the lifecycle the issue is the same lifecycle event are not called when rotating 180 degree from landscape to reverse landscape

Answer (score 1):

The default `screenOrientation` mode behavior is vendor and device specific. For phones, it's typical that only -90°, 0° and 90° are supported.

To support all orientations, add `android:screenOrientation="fullSensor"` to your activity's manifest entry.

Docs: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element#screen

Comment: this not solved my issue, onConfigurationChanged is not called, layout/view is rotating automatically. however I cannot handle events, i can only handle rotation from portrait to  landscape 180 degree rotation doesn't call callback

Answer (score 0):

Kind of late answer but it may help in the future.

Call `setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_FULL_SENSOR)` in your main activity's onCreate method.

Below works for me.

```
MainActivity.this.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_FULL_SENSOR);
```